# Nav tabs not working as expected

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Please bear with me as I'm extremely new to Meteor. I am attempting to dynamically create both tabs and their respective content within one template using the following code. The expected data does show up, but on my first tab (let's say the value of `{{Name}}` is "FirstTab") I see the `{{Name}}` for all of the items in my `levels` collection. However, when I click on the other tabs, I see only the expected `{{Name}}` values, even when I return to the "FirstTab" tab. Obviously, I'm iterating incorrectly somewhere...but I don't understand why it works when I click out of the first tab. How should I be implementing this?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    {{#each indexedArray levels}}
        {{#if _isFirstIndex }}
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#{{removeSpaces Name}}" aria-controls="{{removeSpaces Name}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{Name}}</a></li>
        {{ else }}
            <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#{{removeSpaces Name}}" aria-controls="{{removeSpaces Name}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{Name}}</a></li>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    {{#each indexedArray levels}}
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="{{removeSpaces Name}}">
        <h2>{{Name}}</h2>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: A more "meteor-like" approach would be to create a reactive variable at the template level that represents the state (selected tab) and use it to determine which tab to render (by setting the var to the desired index, for example), and not create all of the tab contents in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Realized I could just add the same `{{#if _isFirstIndex }}` around the `tabpanel` div to make it work as expected. However, I agree with @MasterAM that this is definitely un-Meteor-like and I'll need to refactor following that advice.